# Find $\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}{\frac{1}{(x+y)^{3/2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{a^2}{2(x+y)}\right\}}\,dy\,dx$.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

In my posterior probability computation, I got the following integration and I could not figure it out.

> $$\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}{\frac{1}{(x+y)^{3/2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{a^2}{2(x+y)}\right\}}\,dy\,dx$$     where $a$ is a positive constant

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like this thing diverges, [according to WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty+\frac{1}{%28x%2By%29^{3%2F2}}*exp%28\frac{-a}{2%28x%2By%29}%29dydx). You might have made a mistake while computing the posterior probability.

Comment: @probablyme actually this is the marginal likelihood under the alternative hypothesis which is a part of my equation for the posterior probability.I got the posterior probability equals $(1+a*Above integration)^{-1}$.I guess I should numerically compute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also think that this integral diverges.

$$\int\frac{e^{-\frac{a^2}{2 (x+y)}}}{(x+y)^{3/2}}\,dy=-\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi } }{a}\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{x+y}}\right)$$ $$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{a^2}{2 (x+y)}}}{(x+y)^{3/2}}\,dy=\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi } }{a}\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2x} }\right)$$ provided $\Re(x)>0\lor x\notin \mathbb{R}$ Now, consider $$\int\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t} }\right)\,dt=(t+2) \text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)+\frac{2 e^{-1/t} \sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\pi
   }}$$ $$I=\int_0^b\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t} }\right)\,dt=(b+2) \text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\right)+\frac{2 \sqrt{b} e^{-1/b}}{\sqrt{\pi
   }}-2$$ Now, for large values of $b$, $$I=-2+\frac{4 \sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{4 }{3 \sqrt{\pi b
   }}+O\left(\frac{1}{b^{3/2}}\right)$$ which would then make $$\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi } }{a}\int_0^b\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2x} }\right)=-\sqrt{2 \pi } a+4 \sqrt{b}+\frac{2}{3} a^2
   \sqrt{\frac{1}{b}}+O\left(\frac{1}{b^{3/2}}\right)$$

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.If I change the integral as following, would it be different from the original one.In my computation $x^{2}$ and $y^{2}$ are variance and the original integrations are wrt $x^{2}$ and $y^{2}$,    $\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}{\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{a^2}{2(x^2+y^2)}\right\}}\,dy^2\,dx^2$